# Find common lines in 2 files, write common line from file1 and non common line from file 2

Tags: python

I am trying to find common lines in file 1 and file 2.
If the common line exists, i want to write the line from file 2, otherwise print the non common line from file 1.
fin1 and fin2 are the file handles here.
Its reading the lines fine and there are common lines but i am not getting anything at all in teh output file.

```
flag=0
list1=fin1.readlines()
list2=fin2.readlines()
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i.strip() in j.strip():
            frealout.write(j)
            flag=1
            break
    if flag==0:
        frealout.write(j)
    flag=0
```

Here is the input file structure file1

```
ckgridu1n0
top_vli_z399a
```

here is the input file structure 2

```
   input node          ckgridu1n0,  
         input node [195:0]  top_vli_z399a,
```

Comment: try something like [this code](http://codepad.org/tiMdqbU3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

> otherwise print the non common line from file 1

I think you want to do

```
if flag==0:
    frealout.write(i)
```

instead of

```
if flag==0:
    frealout.write(j)
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i was that stupid ! Sometimes i question my sanity.

Comment: @Illusionist However, I'm curious that doesn't `if flag==0: frealout.write(j)` and `if i.strip() in j.strip(): frealout.write(j)` would always print out the line in `list1`, which result in all the lines in list1 would be printed out anyway.

Comment: yes i did have a typo it should have been frealout.write(i) in the 2nd last line

Comment: @Illusionist I mean, would it be different if you just use these three lines `list2=fin2.readlines()
for line in list1: frealout.write(line)` to replace with your origin code ? Essentially all the data in `fin1` will be printed out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> if flag==0:
>         frealout.write(j)

you write `j` value out of it's visibility scope.
It really is not initialized at that point
You should change `j` to `i`

> if flag==0:
>         frealout.write(i)

Comment: what you are saying about visibility scope is [not really true](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/), so be careful. The scopes in Python work in a pretty special way.